# Show photo/video slideshow with photo captions

Tags: software-recommendation, video, photo-management, slideshow, digikam

I'm trying to find a straightforward way to create a date-ordered slideshow from a directory that contains a mix of photos and videos (e.g. the output of a smartphone camera from a holiday). Ideally the slideshow will include the photo metadata (EXIF) captions too at the bottom of the screen, although this isn't absolutely necessary.

So far I've looked at a few solutions, here is why each one fails:

**Digikam** - slideshows work well with photos (incl. showing captions) but don't include video files

**gThumb** - like Digikam the slideshow feature ignores videos. Browsing through the directory in full screen mode plays videos but there's a great big 'properties' dialog that takes up a 3rd of the screen that I can't get rid of

**Kdenlive** - very fiddly requires that I manually insert the video files between the image files to get the date ordering right. Doesn't show the captions

**VLC** - only shows the video file and ignores the image files, when showing image files goes by filename and not date

**ffDiaporama** - broken on Ubuntu 14.04, crashes with

```
Preset /usr/share/ffDiaporama/libx264-hq.ffpreset specified for stream 0:0, but could not be opened.
```

***Edit***:
I searched around a bit more and found that KDE's Gwenview might be the closest solution to what I want here:

**Gwenview** - Open the first image in the folder with Gwenview. View->Sort By->Date. Click 'Fullscreen' and move the mouse to bring up the on-screen controls, click the 'play' icon to start a slideshow. This shows the photos and plays videos.
Unfortunately the delay before switching images is not configurable (seems to be 5 seconds by default) but you can use the arrow keys or mouse to move to the next photo or video when you want. Also does not display captions.

Answer (score 3):

Install [ffDiaporama](http://ffdiaporama.tuxfamily.org/) from stable repository. It's working.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ffdiaporamateam/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffdiaporama
```

Answer (score 0):

In gwenview
Go to plugins > tools > advanced slideshow

If Plugins is empty (by default I think kubuntu doesn't install them) you need to add kipi-plugins I think. There may be a helper anyway once go to Plugins

Comment: The 'Advanced Slideshow' plugin is the same one as used in Digikam and it doesn't play videos (I've already tried this in both digikam and gwenview)